# Werkzeug without ORM

Tags: python, orm, werkzeug

How do I use the Werkzeug framework without any ORM like SQLAlchemy? In my case, it's a lot of effort to rewrite all the tables and columns in SQLAlchemy from existing tables & data.

How do I query the database and make an object from the database output?

In my case now, I use Oracle with cx_Oracle. If you have a solution for MySQL, too, please mention it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what i looking for http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/SqlSoup
and ht*p://spyced.blogspot.com/2006/04/introducing-sqlsoup.html

so i don't have to declare the table to get the object

rp = db.bind.execute('select * from mupp')
a = rp.fetchall()
a[0].name

that's great...thanks for all inspiring response

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy supports reflection so you don't have to do that. Take a look at the [autoload parameter of `Table`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table), [you can even make this work with the ORM.](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem to use normal DB API, issue regular SQL queries, etc? cx_Oracle even has connection pooling biolt in to help you manage connections.

Comment: maybe i'm not looking for plain query to oracle but something like models in codeigniter that for python. any idea??